# External links in Cordova

Tags: html, css, swift, cordova

hi I'm using Cordova to redirect me to my own site that is built for the iPhone. i know cordova isn't used like that but I wanna publish my app and I already finished programming it. so i have technical question and one besides the point

firstly

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
  <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
  <title>inAppBrowser</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
    cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://mysite .com', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

so my site has external links how do i make them open in safari because there is no back button i tried changing my XML to having only my site as allow intent but still not working so can someone help me out please

will my application be considered hybrid or webapp because the app store doesn't accept webapps

Comment: In case you didn't know, there is no word spelled as 'extrnal.'  Secondly, the first letter of the first word in each sentence must be capitalized in English.

Comment: Thank you so much for bringing this to my attention. If you don't mind, can you help me with the main question?